# VML Text on top of Image Outlook Email

Tags: html, outlook, vml

Anyone knows how to add Text on top of the image using VML / HTML?
I'm trying to display the text ''image title'' in front of the image at the bottom left corner but it doesn't work:

```
<!--[if mso]>                    
                    <v:image xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="position: relative; width: 700px; height: 170px; z-index:1" src="https://www.tutorialsplane.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/nature-3082832_640.jpg" />
                            <v:textbox style="v-text-anchor:bottom" inset="0,0,0,0">
                                <div style="position: relative; text-align: center;">
                                    <font color="#ffffff">
                                        <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; padding: 20px; font-family: Georgia, serif; font-size: 50px; z-index:2">
                                            <p style="color: white">&nbsp;&nbsp;Image Title</p>
                                    </font>
                                </div>                                            
                            </v:textbox>

<![endif]-->
```

Thank you